# Cannot fetch Stormglass SGTideExtremesPointRequest data

Tags: swift, api

I have SGCoordinate that I'm interested in getting extreme tide times. I'm using StormGlass 1.0.0 Xcode dependency and when I try to fetch "tideRequest" I get a type mismatch error. What am I doing wrong?

```
let requestedCoord = SGCoordinate.init(latitude: 43.2844 , longitude: -2.1699)
let tideEndpoint = SGTideExtremesPointRequest(coordinate: requestedCoord,datum: .meanSeaLevel)
let tideRequest = SGRequest(endpoint: tideEndpoint)

tideRequest.fetch {
    _tideData in //Type Mismatch Error
    do
    {
        let _data = try _tideData.get().data
       
        self.fetchedTideData.highTide = [formatter.string(from: _data.first!.time)]
        self.fetchedTideData.lowTide = [formatter.string(from: _data.first!.time)]
    } catch {
        print(error) 
    }
}
```

When I change the request type with other type of data in the same spot it works fine. It's probably simple but any help would be greatly appreciated.